# Trouble using If[] within TabView Manipulate control

Tags: dynamic, manipulate

If I place an `If` in the "body" of a `Manipulate` as in:

```
Manipulate[tick;
 Dynamic@If [ s1 == 1,
   {"m1 ", Manipulator[Dynamic[m1, (m1 = #; tick = Not[tick]) &], {1, 4}], " ", Dynamic[m1]},
   {"m2 ", Manipulator[Dynamic[m2, (m2 = #; tick = Not[tick]) &], {0, 1}], " ", Dynamic[m2]}
   ]
 , TabView[{ "1" -> Grid[tabNumber = t1;(*Dynamic@*){ }],
   "2" -> Grid[tabNumber = t2; {
      {"s1 ", SetterBar[Dynamic[s1, (s1 = #; tick = Not[tick]) &], Range[2]], " ", Dynamic[s1]}
      }]
   }, Dynamic@tabNumber]
 , {{tick, False}, None} , {{tabNumber, 1}, None}
 , {{t1, 1}, None} , {{t2, 2}, None} , {{m1, 1}, None} , {{m2, 1}, None} , {{s1, 1}, None}
 , TrackedSymbols :> {tick}, ControlPlacement -> Left
 ]
```

Then the selection of the s1 `SetterBar` control switches the m1/m2 control in the `Manipulate` display without any trouble:

[image: If within Manipulate]

I'd like to have this condition within the `TabView` control, something like:

```
Manipulate[tick;
 Dynamic@If[tabNumber == t1, Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}],
   Plot[1 - x^2, {x, 0, 1}]]
 , TabView[{
   "1" ->(*Dynamic@*)Grid[tabNumber = t1;(*Dynamic@*){
      (*Dynamic@*)If [ s1 == 1,
       {"m1 ", Manipulator[ Dynamic[m1, (m1 = #; tick = Not[tick]) &], {1, 4}], " ", Dynamic[m1]},
       {"m2 ", Manipulator[ Dynamic[m2, (m2 = #; tick = Not[tick]) &], {0, 1}], " ", Dynamic[m2]}
       ]
      }],
   "2" -> Grid[tabNumber = t2; {
      {"s1 ", SetterBar[Dynamic[s1, (s1 = #; tick = Not[tick]) &], Range[2]], " ", Dynamic[s1]}
      }]
   }, Dynamic@tabNumber]
 , {{tick, False}, None} , {{tabNumber, 1}, None}
 , {{t1, 1}, None} , {{t2, 2}, None} , {{m1, 1}, None} , {{m2, 1}, None} , {{s1, 1}, None}
 , TrackedSymbols :> {tick}, ControlPlacement -> Left
 ]
```

However, instead of one of the two desired controls showing up within the `Tab, this produces`Grid[...]` text instead:

[image: Grid text in TabView]

Is there a way to get the If condition in the Tab definition to evaluate before the `TabView`?  I have tried all the variations of `Dynamic@` that I can think of, but they didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out with the help of [Dynamically choosing which Manipulate controls to use](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11200/dynamically-choosing-which-manipulate-controls-to-use) .  That answer used `Control`@, which doesn't seem to be required here.  However, it also pushes the `If`, up out of the control.  That appears to be the trick:

```
Manipulate[tick;
 Dynamic@If[tabNumber == t1, Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}],
   Plot[1 - x^2, {x, 0, 1}]]
 , Dynamic@If[ s1 == 1, tv[ t1gs1 ], tv[ t1gs2 ] ]
 , {{tick, False}, None} , {{tabNumber, 1}, None}
 , {{t1, 1}, None} , {{t2, 2}, None} , {{m1, 1}, None} , {{m2, 1}, None} , {{s1, 1}, None}

 , TrackedSymbols :> {tick}, ControlPlacement -> Left

 , Initialization :>
  {
   t1gs1 := {{"m1 ", Manipulator[Dynamic[m1, (m1 = #; tick = Not[tick]) &], {1, 4}], " ", Dynamic[m1]}} ;
   t1gs2 := { {"m2 ", Manipulator[Dynamic[m2, (m2 = #; tick = Not[tick]) &], {0, 1}], " ", Dynamic[m2]} } ;

   tv[pred_] := TabView[{
      "1" -> Grid[tabNumber = t1; pred ],
      "2" -> Grid[tabNumber = t2; { {"s1 ", SetterBar[Dynamic[s1, (s1 = #; tick = Not[tick]) &], Range[2]], " ", Dynamic[s1]} } ]
      }, Dynamic@tabNumber] ;
   }
 ]
```

I also had to introduce some helper functions for the `TabView` contents to avoid a whole lot of duplication.

EDIT: another way that works, without requiring global symbols that can be problematic, is to fix the bracing, ensuring that any `If` statements are entirely constrained within those braces.  An example of that, structurally a bit different than above, is:

```
Manipulate[tick;
 Switch[tabNumber, tab1, Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}], tab2, Plot[1 - x^2, {x, 0, 1}], _, Plot[Sin[v x] E^(-x), {x, 0, 1}]],
 TabView[{
   "1" -> Column[{Row[{"1 selected"}]}],
   "2" -> Column[{Row[{"2 selected"}]}],
   "3" -> Grid[{
      {Row[{"3 selected"}]},
      {Dynamic@If[s1 == 1, "",
         Manipulator[Dynamic[v, (v = #; tick = Not[tick]) &], {1, 10}
          , ImageSize -> Tiny, ContinuousAction -> False,
          AppearanceElements -> {(*"InputField"*)}]]}
      }]}
  , Dynamic[tabNumber, (tabNumber = #; tick = Not[tick]) &]
  ]
 , {{tick, False}, None} , {{s1, 1}, {1, 2}} , {{v, 1}, None}
 , {{tabNumber, 1}, None}, {{tab1, 1}, None}, {{tab2, 2}, None}, {{tab3, 3}, None}
 , TrackedSymbols :> {tick}
 , ControlPlacement -> Left
]
```

This method also uses the second argument of Dynamic to collect tabNumber, which doesn't have side effects that interfere with SaveDefinitions.